# Knockout: Propper way of Option-Binding with Model-Instances

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

By the nature of instances, new anObject({id: 1}) != new anObject({id: 1}).

This leads me to a problem regarding Knockout:
I have an array of possible options (all instances of an model with different property-values) and another model which helds a selection.
From a UI-perspective, I have a simple `<select data-bind="options: [...]`-binding, which works fine as long as I select an option.

Because my ViewModel can get stored and later recalled in a new applyBinding, I get into the problem of my data-bind not recognizing my selected value and consequentially removing the value.

Now my simplest solution is some sort of initialisation-function, which loops through the options and selects the right model-instance through an id-comparison. After I have the correct instance, I then can apply it to the "selectedValue"-property.

I didn't tried it out yet, but I don't see how it wouldn't work.
Because I don't think that this a strange requirment and a lot of people are using Knockout - I was hoping there was some nicer way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Knockout.js documentation for "optionsValue": http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

> Typically you’d only want to use optionsValue as a way of ensuring
>   that KO can correctly retain selection when you update the set of
>   available options. For example, if you’re repeatedly getting a list of
>   “car” objects via Ajax calls and want to ensure that the selected car
>   is preserved, you might need to set optionsValue to "carId" or
>   whatever unique identifier each “car” object has, otherwise KO won’t
>   necessarily know which of the previous “car” objects corresponds to
>   which of the new ones.

Comment: thank you, I've read that, but that's not a great solution, in fact I find even mine more convenient, although it's far away from ideal